# I'm using mesibo android sdk to implement chat app but I have an issue with receiving voice call

Tags: android, sdk, chat, voice, mesibo

when the app is totally closed, I don't receive calls, I don't know why
can any one help me ??
I'm using this code to setup mesibo :

```
  Mesibo.getInstance().init(this)
  Mesibo.addListener(this)
  Mesibo.setRestartListener(this)
  Mesibo.setSecureConnection(true)
  Mesibo.setAccessToken(user?.mesiboToken)
  val myProfile = UserProfile()
  myProfile.name = user?.name
  myProfile.address = user?.mesiboAddress
  Mesibo.setDatabase("mydb", 0)
  MesiboCall.getInstance().init(applicationContext)
  Mesibo.setAppInForeground(this, 0, true)
  Mesibo.start()
  val profiles = Mesibo.getUserProfiles()
  profiles.forEach { (key, profile) ->
    val split = key.split("-")
    if (!split.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      val userProfile = UserProfile()
      userProfile.name = split[0]
      userProfile.address = key
      Mesibo.setUserProfile(userProfile, false)
    }
  }
  Mesibo.setPushToken(TokenManager.getInstance().getFCMToken())
```

**also I have implement all Mesibo Call Listeners**

Answer (score 0):

> Once the operating system suspends your app, it will not be able to
> run and hence receive new messages or calls until it is activated
> again. Hence, when your app has a new message or a new incoming call,
> you need to wake up your app from the sleep state to deliver messages
> and calls in real-time. This is where you need to send push
> notifications. Push notification wakes up your app and moves it from
> the sleep state to the active state. Once the app moves to the active
> state, Mesibo will automatically connect and start receiving messages
> and calls.

From https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/push-notifications/